# Adding two times together in php when value is greater than 24

Tags: php, sql, date, time

I'm trying to add two time variables together, and store this new value in field called timetaken in a SQL table, which works fine unless the total is over 24 hours, in which case it resets. From what I've read and tried so far, this is because it carries over into a day. However I've not managed to come up with a solution.

`$timeTakenSoFar` is the current `timetaken` field from the SQL table. 
`$timeTaken` is taken from a form, which the user inputs in the format `00:00:00`

```
$time = strtotime($timeTakenSoFar) + strtotime($timeTaken) - strtotime('00:00:00');
$totalTimeTaken = date('H:i:s', $time);

$stmt = $connection->prepare("UPDATE readings SET timeTaken=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $totalTimeTaken, $id2);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What solution would you want when the two times end up being more than 24 hours? Do you want to store the day, or something else? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Thanks! I want it storing as a duration of time.  If the first time is 23:00:00 and the second time is 05:00:00, I would want the result to be 28:00:00.

Comment: Your problem is in the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) call. `date()` is used to format times, but it doesn't do any kind of calculation on them, it will only format the timestamp to be displayed as requested. You can test this by doing for example `date('s', $time);`, this will display the seconds in your timestamp (which should be zero). I haven't done any php for a while so I'm not sure if there's a specific function to achieve what you want but it should quite easy to roll your own.

Comment: That said, to store times or dates as a string in a database it's usually a bad idea as it's very error-prone, as you have probably realised by now. Usually it's preferable to store the data with the appropriate type (`TIME`, `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP`, etc.) depending on the database and what you are trying to store, and only convert or format that data in the last instance just before displaying it. This also make mathematical operations with them quite straightforward. I hope that someone will be able to provide a complete answer for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here is from another posted, but modified to go past 24 hrs.

```
$time1="24:00:00";
    $time2="00:45:00";
    class times_counter {
        private $hou = 0;
        private $min = 0;
        private $sec = 0;
        private $totaltime = '00:00:00';
        public function __construct($times){
             if(is_array($times)){

                $length = sizeof($times);

                for($x=0; $x <= $length; $x++){
                        $split = explode(":", @$times[$x]); 
                        $this->hou += @$split[0];
                        $this->min += @$split[1];
                        $this->sec += @$split[2];
                }

                $seconds = $this->sec % 60;
                $minutes = $this->sec / 60;
                $minutes = (integer)$minutes;
                $minutes += $this->min;
                $hours = $minutes / 60;
                $minutes = $minutes % 60;
                $hours = (integer)$hours;
                $hours += $this->hou ;
                $this->totaltime = $hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds;
            }
        }

        public function get_total_time(){
            return $this->totaltime;
        }

    }

    $times = array(
        '00:32:00',
        '25:15:00',
        '25:40:20',
        '02:05:16'
    );

    $counter = new times_counter($times);
    echo $counter->get_total_t//outputs:
    //10:30:36ime();`
```